# Check membership of elements of one column in another, mySQL

Tags: mysql

How would I go about counting values that appear in column 1, but not column 2. They are from the same table, without using subqueries or anything fancy. They may or may not share other common column values (like col 3 = col 4) but this doesnt matter.

I have it almost working with subqueries, but cannot figure how to do it without. The only problem (I think) is it will count something twice if the primary key (composed of col1,col3,col4) are different but col1 is the same.

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*)
FROM mytable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM mytable
  WHERE t1.column1 = mytable.column2
);
```

But like I said, I'm trying to figure this without subqueries anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM mytable mt1
  LEFT JOIN mytable mt2 ON mt1.column1 = mt2.column2
WHERE mt2.column IS NULL
```

Comment: nice clean, and easy to understand solution

Answer (score 0):

Please see this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(IF(column1 = column2, 0, 1)) as c
FROM
    mytable
```

Comment: I think this is comparing straight across. Maybe I was unclear :/ I need to see if each individual element in column1 exists at all in column2 in any row.

Comment: Then you do Cartesian multiplication like this: oops, will post a new answer